# Using MediaPlayer class in Java (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I want the background music to repeat as long as the user stays in a particular screen. Is there a function in the MediaPlayer class that allows you to do the above task?

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Overridepublic void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context,kids_quiz.class);

        startActivity(intent);

        player=MediaPlayer.create(Games.this,R.raw.macdonald);

        player.start();

    }
});
```

Comment: Show some code please. Do you have a specific issue? No one will write your program from zero.

Comment: Please answer!!! ??? What is this? No one will help you if you don't ask the right question

Comment: The method you are looking for is setLooping(true), you need to read the documentation

Comment: ok I included the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start it when you are in that Activity, setLooping to true, and when the user leaves the screen destroy the mediaPlayer in Activity.onDestroy(and maybe onPause depending on what you want to accomplish) method. 
Remember it is important to destroy a mediaPlayer when you're done with it as it consumes a lot of resources.